# I want to not listing duplicated numbers of arrays

Tags: python, python-2.7

> my current output [1,2,3,4,5,6] [2,1,3,4,5,6] [3,2,1,4,5,6] ...
>   [6,5,4,3,2,1]
>   all numbers are same but i want like this output only
>   one [1,2,3,4,5,6] how can i do this

```
import    os
import    sys

numbers=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
x=[]
for i1 in numbers:
    for i2 in numbers:
        for i3 in numbers:
            for i4 in numbers:
                for i5 in numbers:
                    for i6 in numbers:
                        if i1 not in (i2,i3,i4,i5,i6) and i2 not in (i1,i3,i4,i5,i6) and i3 not in (i1,i2,i4,i5,i6) and i4 not in (i1,i2,i3,i5,i6) and i5 not in (i1,i2,i3,i4,i6) and i6 not in (i1,i2,i3,i4,i5):
                            x.append([i1,i2,i3,i4,i5,i6])

i=0
while i < len(x):
    print x[i]
    i=i+1
```

Comment: `list(set(list(itertools.chain(l1,l2,l3))))`

Comment: It is not really clear to me what the expected output should be. Why not simply use `numbers` immediately?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing duplicates in lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think OP has multiple list and he want to keep only unique elements.

Comment: Why would you want to do all that work, and only keep the `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` list?

Comment: You could also condense your 6 loops to `itertools.product(numbers, repeat = len(numbers))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set()` it!

Just use `set()` on the list you want to remove duplicates from. Then `list()` it to cast it to a list.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather unclear question, but to remove duplicates from a list:

```
nums = [1,2,3,3,4,5,6]
x = []
for i in nums:
    if i not in x:
        x.append(i)

[print(i) for i in x] # output -> 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

And to only get uniques from several lists:

```
nums = [1,2,3,3,4,5,6]
nums2 = [2,1,3,4,4,5,7,8]

lists = nums + nums2

x = []
for i in lists:
    if i not in x:
        x.append(i)

[print(i) for i in x] # output -> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

## Edit and answer

To get only unique sets of numbers:

```
nums1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
nums2 = [3,2,1,6,5,4]
nums3 = [4,3,2,5,1,6]
nums4 = [2,3,4,5,6,7]

s1 = set(nums1)
s2 = set(nums2)
s3 = set(nums3)
s4 = set(nums4)

sets = [s1, s2, s3, s4]
uniq = []
for s in sets:
    if s not in uniq:
        uniq.append(s)

for u in uniq:
    [print(i, end=' ') for i in u]
    print() # output -> {1,2,3,4,5,6} and {2,3,4,5,6,7}
```

Using sets is not required, but will ensure you have no duplicates inside the original lists and things will be easier in other ways as well.

Comment: It might be better to use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets).

Comment: @internet_user It's convenient, yes. But it seems quite clear OP doesn't have a lot of experience. So it's worth stating how to manually check for duplicates.

Comment: @AltayKarakalpaklı I edited the question for you and included an answer above according to your answer that was deleted. Please try to be precise in your questions in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) in python to achieve this.

Suppose you have multiple lists, and want to put all of the unique elements from these lists into one array, you can code it this way.

```
number_list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
number_list_2 = [4,3,2,1,6]
number_list_3 = [2,4,1,3,7]
no_dupes = []

[no_dupes.append(item) for item in number_list_1 if item not in no_dupes]
[no_dupes.append(item) for item in number_list_2 if item not in no_dupes]
[no_dupes.append(item) for item in number_list_3 if item not in no_dupes]

print str(no_dupes)
```

This would return: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

Comment: no i'am saying that we have three arrays 1,2,3,4; 4,3,2,1 and 2,4,1,3 and these 3 arrays contain same numbers how can i show only one unique array

Comment: If all the three arrays are going to always have the same numbers, they why not just sort one of them? `array.sort()`

Comment: Well that is kind of up to you to figure out. It is still very unclear what you are trying to do, or what problem you are trying to solve. I only mentioned `array.sort()` because you said all lists will contain the same numbers, but in different order. So why even process them at all, is what I was thinking.